# Download multiple image data from s3 Amazon

Tags: android, amazon-s3

How to download multiple image from s3 Amazon. i google many question but not get any good answer. I have a listView and i want to get all image data to set image data in adapter. Please suggest me right way.

Comment: You can use any image loading library like glide, universal image loader, picasso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can download like this

```
 Resources res = mContext.getResources();
        String awsKey = res.getString(R.string.aws_key);
        String awsSecretKey = res.getString(R.string.aws_secret_key);
        String awsBucketName = res.getString(R.string.aws_bucket_name);
        AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(
                new BasicAWSCredentials(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.aws_key),
                        mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.aws_secret_key)));

        S3ObjectInputStream content = s3Client.getObject(awsBucketName, url).getObjectContent();
```

this code write in Asyntask for working well